# MacBook Pro keeps restarting - newbie

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro to Yosemite. Everything was fine ... then suddenly the MacBook Pro does not start up. It boots with some distorted graphics, and then just immediately restarts.

I tried Recovery by pressing shift key. Command + Shift. Nothing. Same thing...Apple logo..progress bar, grey screen, fan speeds up ... shutdown.

I tried [Apple's recommendations](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1533). But surprisingly same sequence..

1. Option-Command-P-R -- It did give me sound twice and above sequence
   repeats. (I don't see those icon etc for hardware test..why ?)
2. Pressed shift, same sequence repeats.
3. Command V Video here ... no error but same sequence ... it shows grey
   screen and restarts.

Comment: do you have a console log for us ? can you start in Safe mode?, do you have external drive to start from it ? have you run the Apple Hardware Test ?

Answer (score 1):

What is the year and model of your MacBook Pro? There is a known graphics failure in the 2011 models of MacBook Pros that is now leading to a [class-action lawsuit](http://9to5mac.com/2014/10/28/apple-class-action-lawsuit-2011-macbook-pro-gpu-graphics-issues/) .

I would also try resetting just the SMC by pressing Shift+Control+Option+Power button at the same time while the computer is off and plugged into power. (You only reset the PRAM according to the steps you have done above.)

Comment: I have late 2011 model. And I bought it from India.

Comment: That lawsuit does not apply to me. its for AMD GPU. I have Intel. (Lawsuit for earlier 2011 model. Mine is late). Can I check if which hardware is failing ? Or is it really hardware issue only ? This is my screen video. Does not show anything abnormal. Some additional drivers. Is there a way to wipeout system ? and install again..How can I check if my harddrive is ok ?http://youtu.be/3J78KHuJsO0

Answer (score 0):

Failing all of that, take it into an Apple store and have an Apple Genius look at it. Or go to a local store that does Mac repairs...

But basically your upgrade to Yosemite coincided (coincidentally, **very** unlikely that it caused it) with a hardware failure. Like Alex said possibly a graphics card failure...

But get your model and serial number and check out his link then bring it into an Apple store or an Apple Authorized Service Provider.

Comment: That lawsuit does not apply to me. its for AMD GPU. I have Intel. (Lawsuit for earlier 2011 model. Mine is late) Can I check if which hardware is failing ? Or is it really hardware issue only ? This is my screen video. Does not show anything abnormal. Some additional drivers. Is there a way to wipeout system ? and install again..How can I check if my harddrive is ok ?youtu.be/3J78KHuJsO0 –  Jigar Shah just now   edit

Answer (score 0):

If there is a progress bar and it shuts down, this probably means that your hard-drive has corrupted. Hold Command R and then a globe should appear. Connect to your internet and then wait for it to load. If it brings you to disk utility you can use your backup on time machine, but if you don't have one, you most likely will lose all your stuff.

Comment: Nothing happens after command + r.  It just restarts